# change the source colors in plot.simmr_input

Tags: r

I am trying to learn Stable Isotope Analysis and find the package simmr very helpful.  When creating plots for simmr_input information, the documentation states how to add arguments to the plot via ggplot attributes.   I have been able to change most things I need, but the one thing I cannot seem to do is choose source colors to my liking.  Does any one know what command needs to be changed to do that?

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding `scale_fill_manual` after the plot call to override what is specified in the function.

```
plot(simmr_out, type = "boxplot") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#53698F", "#71ACAD", "#99A3DE"))
```

Make sure that the number of colors matches the number of sources.